# How to pass multiple values of different types to different functions

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python so I'm trying to practice by making a simple macro-nutrient calculator.  I'm not quite sure how to pass certain values to different functions.

Here is my code

```
def Macro_input():
    Percent_protein = input("Percentage of Protein: ") 
    float(Percent_protein)
    Percent_carb = input("Percentage of Carbohydrates: ")
    float(Percent_carb)
    Percent_fat = input("Percentage of Fats: ")
    float(Percent_fat)
    Macro_dict = {'Protein': Percent_protein, 'Carbohydrate': Percent_carb, 'Fats': Percent_fat}
    Macro_sum = Percent_protein + Percent_carb + Percent_fat
    return Macro_sum 

def Total_macro_check(Macro_sum):

    #perhaps put all input into a dictionary? Macro['Protein':num, 'Carb':num, 'Fat':num]

    if Macro_sum == 100:
        print "You macronutrients percentages are \n Protein: "#, Macro_dict['Protein'], "%"    #list for P/C/F --> %d
    elif Macro_sum < 100:
        print "Total percentages do not add up to 100. Please reenter percentages."
    #go back to function that asks for Macros
    elif Macro_sum > 100:
        print "Total percentages surpass 100. Please reenter percentages."
    #go back to function that asks for Macros

def main():
    print "Please enter your macro-nutrients"
    Total_macro_value = Macro_input()

    Total_macro_check(Total_macro_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I want to do is output a Dictionary (Macro_dict),
So I can print it out if the sum of all macros (`Macro_sum`) is 100.
But I also want to check if `Macro_sum` equals 100.
This means I have to output a value `Macro_sum` into the function `Total_macro_check`.

However I feel as though if my `Macro_input` function returned `Macro_sum` and `Macro_dict`,
I cannot use its output in `Total_macro_check` due to it returning more than one value, while `Total_macro_check` only accepts 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to contain the values plus helper functions:

```
class MacroInput(object):
    def __init__(self, protein, carb, fat):
        self.protein, self.carb, self.fat = protein, carb, fat

    def sum(self):
        return self.protein + self.carb + self.fat
```

You can create an instance of this in `Macro_input()` and then pass that instance around. `def Total_macro_check(Macro_sum)` would then become:

```
def Total_macro_check(input):
    sum = input.sum()
    if sum == 100:
        print "You macronutrients percentages are \n Protein:", input.protein, "%"    #list for P/C/F --> %d
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function Macro_Input is bogey.
I don't think this line behave as you think it does.

```
float(Percent_protein)
```

This is casting Percent_protein to float yes, but it's not assigning that value to anything.

Your func should be.

```
def Macro_input():
    Percent_protein = float(input("Percentage of Protein: "))
    Percent_carb = float(input("Percentage of Carbohydrates: "))
    Percent_fat = float(input("Percentage of Fats: "))
    Macro_dict = {'Protein': Percent_protein, 'Carbohydrate': Percent_carb, 'Fats': Percent_fat}
    Macro_sum = Percent_protein + Percent_carb + Percent_fat
    return (Macro_dict,Macro_sum)
```

Now it will return the dictionary and sum as you want.
You can get them out with.

```
(dict,sum) = Macro_input()
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question title, but it answers what his problem actually is with his code in the question.

Comment: ahyeah I see you're right now actually. I just assumed (as asses do) from seeing that problem and the very end of the question that he was wanting to output each individual sum as he wasn't getting it to return what he wanted.

Comment: @KillianDS Should be fixed now to answer the ACTUAL question.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `Macro_input()` to return a tuple of `Macro_dict` and `Macro_sum`

```
def Macro_input():
    # your code
    return Macro_sum, Macro_dict
```

Then you in your main function you can unpack the returned tuple into two variables like this:

```
def main():
    print "Please enter your macro-nutrients"
    Total_macro_value, Macro_dict = Macro_input()

    Total_macro_check(Total_macro_value)
```